# How to add footer in every page in html2pdf in codeigniter

Tags: php, html2pdf

i am using html2pdf in our codeigniter project the problem is how can i add footer text in pdf in every page.

i have added this code

```
$html .= '<page_footer style="color: #D3D3D3; text-align: center;">';
$html .= 'Account managed by R.K.Kapoor & Co.';
$html .= '</page_footer>';
$html .= '</page>';
```

the result is here footer is showing but not showing in every pdf page and i want bottom padding in text kindly help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add  footer attribute on your openning page tag :
`<page  footer="page">`

And place your page_footer tag **just below** the page_header if you have it or below the page tag . Not at the botom of the page like in htlml .

Comment: please valid my answer ;)